# Change price label from MYR to RM in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, final-price

In magento 2.4.4p2 commerce I am trying to change the pricing label from MYR to RM

[image]

But I am not able to found ways to change it, I am able to find this source code which purpose is to show the pricing

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
```

I have extend this source code as necessary from

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/projecta/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

I am not sure how to change this $block->renderAmount accordingly so that it change from MYR to RM, or can this be done through the admin panel ?

Comment: Why you want to change using code if admin has section to change currency symbol...?

Comment: Already try to change from Stores >> Currency >> Currency Symbols , clear cache and everything but the symbol does not change

Comment: Have you checked store specific, switch store views check if checkbox checked or unchecked?

Comment: I go to Stores > Settings > All Stores and see there is only 1 store, this is default magento fresh installation, I think this issue is from the core magento file